# How to solve access denial for JUnit test reports with Maven in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit

I am trying to get Jenkins configured with Maven so I can publish my test reports thanks to Jenkins.

I do not use any source code management, my Maven version is 3.3.3, and the goal I have given is "test".

Since Maven project does not seem to allow to publish JUnit test reports without using a module, I try to build it with a freestyle project.

My Maven project is just fine when I run it locally with Eclipse. However, I have the following issue when I try to build it with Jenkins :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project test: Error while storing the mojo status: /home/kamiel7/ProjetCA_2015/Manipulation/ManipJava/test/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I have no idea what to do to get rid of this access denial. I made sure I enabled maven-surefire-plugin, I tried to see whether this error had a link with the sudoers file. However, I remain a beginner in programming so I could not have many ideas to solve this.

Would you like to help me please ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not that this is the cause of your problem (it happens at compile, before tests are even started): What do you exactly mean by _"publish my test reports"_? Where do you want to publish them?

Comment: Who is the owner and group of `test/target` and `inputFiles.lst` and what are their file permissions?

Comment: When  I say "publish my test report", I mean there is an option you can tickle while configuring your Jenkins project. I also want to have my test report published on my workspace.

Comment: I might have found the problem. Turns out my "target" directory can be read, written or executed. But my inputFiles.lst file cannot be executed. I assume I have to change that using chmod, right ?

Comment: I found out that my inputFiles.lst file could not be executed. So I tried to change this using chmod as a normal user (because the file belongs to the normal user kamiel7). However, although my file can now be executed there were no changes when I ran the build on Jenkins. What step did I miss ?

Comment: Your `target` directory can be `rwx` by _whom_ (owner/group)? Under which user does Jenkins run? To which groups does this user belong? Has this user and/or group `rw-?` I don't think that setting `inputFiles.lst` to `x` will help. As the name implies It contains just  a list of `(.java)` files. Is there an old process hanging around that opened the directory and/or file but didn't close it?

Comment: It was indeed a user issue. Thank you very much for the tip ! I have found a very useful guide to set the user you want Jenkins to run under.
Here is the link for everyone : http://blog.manula.org/2013/03/running-jenkins-under-different-user-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Late answer here for future readers.

I encountered this issue for a while, and then found out that I had an external console (MINGW64) lingering in the background.

As soon as I closed that console, the issue went away. So check if you have any background processes opened that may have gotten hold of some directory or file.